# Converting dict of lists into list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I have a dictionary like so:

```
{
    "var1": [0, 1],
    "var2": ["foo", "bar"]
}
```

Given the above, I want to end up with a list of dictionaries like so:

```
[
    { "var1_0_var2_foo": {"var1": 0, "var2": "foo"} },
    { "var1_1_var2_bar": {"var1": 1, "var2": "bar"} }
]
```

The number of keys and elements in each list in the original dictionary is variable and can be anything.

Here's my messy looking but working solution:

```
source = {
    'x': ['a', 'b'],
    'y': [0, 1],
    'z': ['foo', 'bar']
}

target = []


names = list(source.keys())
lists = list(source.values())
zipped = list(zip(*lists))

for item in zipped:
    full_name = ""
    full_dict = {}
    for idx, value in enumerate(item):
        full_name += f"{names[idx]}_{value}_"
        full_dict[names[idx]] = value
    full_name = full_name.rstrip('_')
    target.append({full_name: full_dict})

print(target)
```

Output:

```
[
    {'x_a_y_0_z_foo': {'x': 'a', 'y': 0, 'z': 'foo'}}, 
    {'x_b_y_1_z_bar': {'x': 'b', 'y': 1, 'z': 'bar'}}
]
```

The above works, but I was wondering if there's a better elegant pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: **want to end up with a list of dictionaries** the list you provided is invalid because it has dictionary declaration syntax (you are specifying `var1_0_var2_foo:` which is only in `dict`s)

Comment: Please edit your question with valid code.

Comment: Sorry, fixed syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pythonic way to do this with list comprehension and lambda functions -

```
d = {
    'x': ['a', 'b'],
    'y': [0, 1],
    'z': ['foo', 'bar']
}

f = lambda x: {i:j for i,j in zip(d,x)}  #Creates the values of final output
g = lambda x: '_'.join([str(j) for i in zip(d,x) for j in i])  #Creates the keys of final output

target = [{g(i):f(i)} for i in zip(*d.values())]
print(target)
```

```
[{'x_a_y_0_z_foo': {'x': 'a', 'y': 0, 'z': 'foo'}},
 {'x_b_y_1_z_bar': {'x': 'b', 'y': 1, 'z': 'bar'}}]
```

Comment: Choosing this as the answer as it avoids any imports whatsoever! Great code.

Comment: glad to help anytime.

Comment: It's ironic to start with _Here is pythonic way_, when the code goes against PEP8 recommendations: _Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier. The first form means that the name of the resulting function object is specifically 'f' instead of the generic '<lambda>'. This is more useful for tracebacks and string representations in general. The use of the assignment statement eliminates the sole benefit a lambda expression can offer over an explicit def statement (i.e. that it can be embedded inside a larger expression)_

Comment: It's ironic to *quote PEP8*, when the first paragraph itself clearly declares: *As PEP 20 says, "Readability counts". A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is the most important. However, know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes style guide recommendations just aren't applicable. When in doubt, use your best judgment.*  Sorry don't mean to be rude :)

Comment: Though I do get where you are coming from, from a readability perspective, I do prefer using lambda functions for 1 liner returns. I had initially crammed all the code into a single line, but that looked nasty!

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain

spam = {'x': ['a', 'b'],
        'y': [0, 1],
        'z': ['foo', 'bar']}

eggs = []
for item in zip(*spam.values()):
    key = '_'.join(chain(*zip(spam.keys(), map(str, item))))
    eggs.append({key:dict(zip(spam.keys(), item))})

print(eggs)
```

output

```
[{'x_a_y_0_z_foo': {'x': 'a', 'y': 0, 'z': 'foo'}},
 {'x_b_y_1_z_bar': {'x': 'b', 'y': 1, 'z': 'bar'}}]
```

Comment: Should've thought of chain, yes. Thanks for sharing the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what the reason for the outer dicts in the output list why not just a list of dict output:

```
data = {
'var1': [0, 1],
'var2': ["foo", "bar"]}

output = [dict(zip(data, vars)) for vars in zip(*data.values())]
```

---

```
[{'var1': 0, 'var2': 'foo'}, {'var1': 1, 'var2': 'bar'}]
```

Comment: May not be what the OP asked for but clearly the more logical way to transform the original dictionary to a list. The keys in the "expected output" make little sense and are unlikely to be of any use. Perhaps looking OP is looking for a filename pattern to store JSON data?

Comment: Correct, if there was no need for that stupid key name, it would be a much simpler problem. I need the keys for a specific unavoidable reason.